# Knopp's theorem about composition of power series from "Theory and Application of Infinite Series"

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Theorem 104 in the Dover edition of Knopp's "Theory and Application of Infinite Series" says (paraphrased):

> Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$
> and $\displaystyle g(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n$ be two power series which converge on open disks $|z| < R_f \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $|z| < R_g \subset \mathbb{C}$, respectively. 
>
> If $r$ is such that
> $0 < r < R_f$ and $\sum_{n \ge 0} |a_n z^n| < R_g$
> whenever $|z| < r$, 
> then the composite function $(g \circ f)(z) = g(f(z))$ is defined when $|z| < r$ and has a (unique) power series expansion there.

The proof uses the condition $\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 0} |a_n z^n| < R_g$ when $|z| < r$ to allow interchanging the order of summation for a double series.

**Here is my question:** 
Am I understanding correctly from complex analysis that we really need only
$\displaystyle |f(z)| = \left|\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \right| < R_g$ when $|z| < r$,
because then we know $g(f(z))$ is an holomorphic function on a disk?

**EDIT:** To clarify, why would Knopp choose to use the condition $\sum_{n \ge 0} |a_n z^n| < R_g$ which is stronger than $\displaystyle |f(z)| < R_g$?

Comment: yes because then $|a_nz^n| < M, |z|<r$ which immediately implies that the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ actually converges absolutely for $|z|<r$ (this is one of the features of power series that make them so useful - eg for Dirichlet series this is not true, we get only conditional convergnence from boundness)

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, appreciate it. My question wasn't about whether or not the series for $f$ and $g$ converge absolutely; I thought that's obvious from the root test. What I was trying to get at was why Knopp may have chosen to use a stronger convergence criterion than necessary. I made an edit.

Comment: I guess the answer is as you noted, because, under the stronger condition (which in fact is equivalent to the weaker one here), one can interchange double series; the result is not only that $(g \circ f)(z)$ is analytic, but also that its power series is as given and that last part requires the interchange

Comment: You are right that in general the disc where $\sum_n |a_n z^n| < R_g$ is strictly smaller than the disc where $|f(z)| < R_g$; the point is that on the first disc one can prove that the composition has the required power series by switching the sums; then of course, you can extend the composition to the second disc and the power series is same there by analytic continuation, so Knopp proves a weaker than optimal result here and the optimal result is as you note; however you still need to go through the intermediate step to prove it (at least this way with switching double series);

Comment: @Conrad I have now caught up to where you were. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: Note: To see this, look at $f(z) = 1 + i z + z^2 + i z^3 = (1+iz)(1+z^2)$.